# reset contents on textarea

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do like this:

1. You will find it is prepared text area with selected sample text and clear button when you launch app
2. You can input in text area
3. When you tap button contents are reset(you will see selected sample text in text area)

now, I can't find how to make like 1.
I wrote in ViewController to do 2. and 3. with simple code like this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var field: UITextView!

      @IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
      field.text = "samplesamplesample"
      field.selectAll(nil)
  }
```

How I get solved my question?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I want show _selected text _ on text field when app launched.
I'm sorry I can't use English...

Comment: Do you want to set text or a placeholder? Refer [img](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-re8QZMoXOGQ/UM1WSNGcZpI/AAAAAAAACkg/D2kXO-K1t2Q/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/iOS%2BUITextField%2Bwith%2Bnumeric%2Bdata%2Bentry%2Band%2Bview%2Boverlay.png). Something like this?

Comment: @nyorotan : Take a look at the answer posted, lemme know if you if have any issue